# Progressive Upload and Encryption with CryptoJS

Tags: filereader, cryptojs

The goal here is to upload a file, encrypt it at the client side, and send the file and its attributes via AJAX to myphpscript.php.  To allow larger files, I want to upload in slices using the FileReader slice method and progressively encrypt the slices using the methods described on the CryptoJS site (https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/).  My code below runs, but only ends up storing a a small portion of the intended entire encrypted file.  Can I progressively upload and encrypt in the way I am describing?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/aes.js"></script>
<script>
    function readBlob(opt_startByte, opt_stopByte) {

        var files = document.getElementById('fileinput').files;
        if (!files.length) {
            alert('Please select a file!');
            return;
        }

        var file = files[0];
        var start = parseInt(opt_startByte) || 0;
        var stop = parseInt(opt_stopByte) || file.size - 1;

        var reader = new FileReader();

        // If we use onloadend, we need to check the readyState.
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
                window.bits.push(aesEncryptor.process(evt.target.result));
            }
        };

        var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
        reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
    }

    function handling(evt) {

        // INITIALIZE PROGRESSIVE ENCRYPTION
        var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(document.getElementById('pass').value);
        var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8);
        window.bits = [];
        window.aesEncryptor = CryptoJS.algo.AES.createEncryptor(key, {iv: iv});

        // LOOP THROUGH BYTES AND PROGRESSIVELY ENCRYPT
        var startByte = 0;
        var endByte = 0;
        while(startByte < document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0].size - 1){
            endByte = startByte + 1000000;
            readBlob(startByte, endByte);
            startByte = endByte;
        }

        // FINALIZE ENCRYPTION AND UPLOAD
        var encrypted = aesEncryptor.finalize();
        encrypted = encodeURIComponent(encrypted);
        var filename = document.getElementById('fileinput').value;
        var file_type = document.getElementById('fileinput').files[0].type;
        var url = 'data=' + encrypted + '&filename=' + filename + '&filetype=' + file_type;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'myphpscript.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: url
        }).success(function(data){
            // Display encrypted data
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Upload Complete.';
        });
        alert(encrypted);

    }
</script>
```

Comment: If you want to upload the data in several chunks, then I’d expect to see you making requests in some kind of loop … but I don’t see that happening?

Comment: Right now the way I am doing this, correct me if I am wrong, is in the section with the comment "LOOP THROUGH BYTES AND PROGRESSIVELY ENCRYPT".  In that while loop, I run the function readBlob which reads a particular slice.

Comment: But you are _sending_ the data to your server outside of that loop, afterwards …

Comment: I see your point; to clarify, I don't necessarily want to upload the data in chunks, I want to progressively encrypt its slices from FileReader and then upload all at once.  Maybe uploading all at once defeats the purpose of the progressive slicing and encrypting, and if so, an alternative would be helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem is the line `var encrypted = aesEncryptor.finalize();`

This is not the encrypted file, but the final 'chunk' produced by the CryptoJS.AES finalizer.

you need to append that to the end of the `window.bits` buffer to yield the fully encrypted file.

Also, you shouldn't be using `window.bits.push`, you should keep hold of a reference to each chunk like this (psuedocode):

```
var prog;
//then in the loop, if chunk is null assign to chunk or else concat:
loop:
    if(!prog)
        prog = cipher.process()
    else
        prog.concat(cipher.process())

//then finalize
prog.concat(cipher.finalize())

//now you're free to do whatever with the encrypted file:
var ciphertext = prog.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

One important thing to keep in mind is that *the chunks may arrive to the encryptor out of order* so you either have to keep track of the order that chunks went into aesEncryptor.process so that you can decrypt in the proper order later *or* queue the chunks and encrypt them in the proper order to begin with.

Comment: Yep, i detail how to do this [here](http://craig-bruce.com/progressive-decryption/)