# Javascript Encrypted File Upload

Tags: javascript, html, file, encryption, upload

Is there a way to use javascript or ajax to encrypt file uploads, if so can you give me an example or link to working example?

Comment: What about http://tutorialzine.com/2013/11/javascript-file-encrypter/ ? It goes over the basics of the FileSystem API introduced in HTML 5 and cryptography within JavaScript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Progressive Upload and Encryption with CryptoJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593574/progressive-upload-and-encryption-with-cryptojs)

Answer (score 11):

The answer is Yes, there is a way to use javascript or ajax to encrypt file uploads. You can use standard Web APIs that have built-in native support in browsers: Use the standard [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) and [WebCrypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API) to get the file from your filesystem and actually encrypt it—along with the [Indexed Database API (indexedDB)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) (if you want) to store the encrypted file on the client side in the browser. A good simple example with working code is at [Upload a file, encrypt it, calculate the hash and store the results using indexedDB](https://gist.github.com/Ayms/6451926).

#### Short summary of how to do it

The first step is just the normal step of creating an `input type=file` element in your HTML, and binding a function to it for getting the file from your filesystem and doing something with it; e.g., use `onsubmit="my_file_handler"`.

After that, inside your `my_file_handler` (or whatever name) function:

1. Use `.files[…]` from that to get the input file(s).
2. Define a function that takes a cryptographic key; within that function:

   - create a new `FileReader` object and use, e.g., `.readAsArrayBuffer(…)` to load the file
   - use [`crypto.subtle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/subtle) to create a new [`SubtleCrypto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto) object
   - use [`.digest(…)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest) with that `SubtleCrypto` object and then [`crypto.subtle.encrypt(…)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/encrypt) to actually encrypt the file with that key
   - use `indexedDB.open(…)` and friends to open a connection to a DB and to put the encrypted file into it.
3. Use [`.importKey(…)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/importKey) to get the key and call your function in step #2 on it to process the input file with it and store it using `indexedDB`.

Answer (score -1):

Use an HTTPS URL to upload the files and the browser will encrypt the data for transit automatically.

(This assumes you want to protect the file in transit and not that you are trying to protect the file from people with admin rights on the server)

Comment: @user1503941 — I refer you to the second paragraph of this answer which makes that point.